# How to set a user-defined variable value to zero whenever id changes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set the variable value to zero whenever the id changes in the following query.

I am trying to achieve this in a single query without performance issues.
Because in the actual query it has more than 10,000 records.
Here is what i have so far,

Sample Table:

```
       create table Test(id integer, title varchar(100));
       insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(2, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(2, "Hello");
       insert into Test(id, title) values(1, "Hello");
```

Here is my query:

```
    select a0.id,a0.title,@a:=@a+a0.id as val from
    (select * from Test order by id) as a0 
    left join
    (select id, @a:=0 from Test group by id) as a1
     on
    a0.id=a1.id
```

-- Output i get from executing the above query:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | title | val |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | Hello |   1 |
|  1 | Hello |   2 |
|  1 | Hello |   3 |
|  1 | Hello |   4 |
|  1 | Hello |   5 |
|  2 | Hello |   7 |
|  2 | Hello |   9 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

-- What i am trying to achieve:

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | title | val |
+----+-------+-----+
|  1 | Hello |   1 |
|  1 | Hello |   2 |
|  1 | Hello |   3 |
|  1 | Hello |   4 |
|  1 | Hello |   5 |
|  2 | Hello |   2 |
|  2 | Hello |   4 |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use another variable to hold the ID from the previous row. Then you can test whether the current ID is the same.

When it changes, reset `@a` to the current ID (not `0`).

```
SELECT a0.id, a0.title, @a := IF(a0.id = @last_id, @a + a0.id, a0.id) AS val, @last_id := a0.id
FROM (SELECT * FROM Test ORDER BY id) AS a0
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 0, @last_id := null) AS vars
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ds23achJdWAAYgdDQFxNf8/0)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way to obtain the same result without another variable to hold the ID from the previous row. Just curious.

Comment: Maybe the new window functions can do this, I'm not really up to speed on them.

Comment: @Barmar . . . MySQL documentation explicitly warns against assigning a variable in one expression and using it in another.  MySQL explicit does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah, I know, but as far as I can tell you can always get away with it. I can never remember the technically correct way to write it (IIRC it involves doing everything in a single `IF()` expression). Feel free to post an answer that does it properly.